# Dereference of a possibly null when blazor binding to a parameter that may be null?

Tags: razor, blazor

How do I write the DOM code differently ?

```
        <select readonly disabled class="form-select" @bind="@project.ProgrammeId">
            @if (_programmes is not null)
            {
                @foreach(var x in _programmes)
                {
                    <option value="@x.Id">@x.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
```

Receiving a warning on the @bind="@project.ProgrammeId" part pf the above select:
"Dereference of a possibly null cpp(CS8602)"

```
@code{

    [Parameter]
    public Project? project {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0$#binding-select-element-options-to-c-object-null-values

Answer (score 1):

The standard pattern for Blazor is

```
@code{

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public Project project {get;set;} = default!;  // no '?'
}
```

The `default!` silences the warnings.
Adding `EditorRequired` transfers the responsibility to where it belongs, to the parent element.

Not completely air-thight but workable, and it keeps most of the benefits of using nullable ref types.

Comment: I like to use the new C# feature "required", in order to remove the primary assignation to "default" which is null for not null able reference type:
`   [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public required Project project {get;set;}`

Comment: @DylanElBar - `required` is of not much help here since Blazor components are create by the renderer. As a dev you don't geţ to use object initializers here. For the same reason we have to use property injection instead of constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the value as nullable which is why you are getting the error.

```cs
[Parameter] public Project? project {get;set;}
```

Doing this:

```cs
[Parameter] public Project? project {get;set;} = default!;
```

doesn't really solve the problem.  You're telling the compiler, I know better.  Which only works if you really do and have set the value before the first render.

In general, you need to declare `Project` as not nullable and assign a value.

```cs
[Parameter] public Project project {get;set;} = new();
```

If `Project` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, then you need to set it in `OnInitialized` or `SetParametersAsync`.

In such situations I tend to do something like this before the first async yield, so I get a blunt reminder if I fail to set the value in my code.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(project);
        await Task.Yield();
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead, i am using @if before trying to emmit html:

```
@if (@project is not null)
{
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Programme</label>
          <select class="form-select" @bind="@project.ProgrammeId">
              @if (_programmes is not null)
              {
                  @foreach(var x in _programmes)
                  {
                      <option value="@x.Id">@x.Name</option>
                  }
              }
```

...
...
...